# Utilizing Partials In Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, async-await, puppeteer

I'm working on refactoring my puppeteer code to reuse repeat code in a partial format. I have multiple items that will repeat the same 4 lines beside for the selector variable. See the example of the 4 lines below.

I want to be able to pass that ACHIEVEMENTS.community_ask_question_id into a repeatable function. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
await page.waitForSelector(ACHIEVEMENTS.community_ask_question_id);  
await page.click(ACHIEVEMENTS.community_ask_question_id,{delay: 500}); 
await page.click(COMPLETE_ACHIEVEMENT, {delay: 500}); 
await page.click(CONFIRM_COMPLETE, {delay: 500});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed create a separate function, just make sure it's an `async` one.

```
async function clicker(page, ACHIEVEMENTS) {
  await page.waitForSelector(ACHIEVEMENTS.community_ask_question_id);  
  await page.click(ACHIEVEMENTS.community_ask_question_id,{delay: 500}); 
  await page.click(ACHIEVEMENTS.COMPLETE_ACHIEVEMENT, {delay: 500}); 
  await page.click(ACHIEVEMENTS.CONFIRM_COMPLETE, {delay: 500});
}

(async() => {

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  /// ...
  for(var i in ACHIEVEMENTS) {
    await clicker(page, ACHIEVEMENTS[i]);
  }
})()
```